# How to filter part of a variable if it is no array?

Tags: filters, hooks, variables

I was wondering if it is possible to filter out a part of a variable, if it is no array. Or can I only replace the whole code, or add code to it?

Let's say I have this code:

```
    $output  = '<select>';
    $output .= '<option value="option 1">Option 1</option>';
    $output .= '<option value="Filter out">Don't show this option</option>';
    $output .= '<option value="option 2">Option 2</option>';
    $output .= '</select>';

    $output = apply_filters( 'my_filter', $output );

return $output;
```

Is there any way to filter out the second option, without rewriting the whole code in the filter?

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

My solution was to use `str_replace`.

Comment: yes you can. you can use `regex` to search for a specific match in a string or use `DOMdocument` to query HTML code in php

Comment: Is that really the best/only way to go?

Comment: Yes, welcome. @RobbTe

Answer (score -1):

The documentation is well explicable of the topic, let's have a look here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/.

In your specific case `my_filter` is applied no matter what, even if there is no value it. To apply the filter only if `is_array()` you could insert a specific instruction directly into your filter like:

```
function example_callback( $output ) {
    if(is_array($output)){
        //do something and replace part of the string with str_replace()
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'my_filter', 'example_callback', 10, 1 );
```

About the `str_replace()` php function read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what i meant. It is not an array, so checking for it does not make sense. I just have a variable and want to take some content from it and replace it with some other content. Then return the variable. Thanks

Comment: @RobbTe it doesn't make sense that you thumb down my answer when you specifically describe in your question "if it is possible to filter out a part of a variable, if it is no array". My answer is a general overview to WP filters and how you can check for arrays (or not) like ASKED. Further, concerning the rest is a PHP question, not a WP related one.

Comment: Again, that was not my question. I did not downvote. Thanks

Comment: Do you realise that you wrote that or it could be misleading right?

Comment: Yes I do, but due to my sample code i thought i would be clear.